# Disable context menu in Internet Explorer control

Tags: c#, .net, events, webbrowser-control, contextmenu

How do I disable the context menu in the IE `WebBrowser` control and instead perform custom handling of the right-click event in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WebBrowser browser;
browser.Document.ContextMenuShowing += new HtmlElementEventHandler(MyCustomContextMenuMethod);
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually:

```
WebBrowser browser;
browser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
```

This pretty much tells the WebBrowser that the right-click context menu is not welcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
AddHandler Me.WebBrowser1.Document.ContextMenuShowing, AddressOf WebContextMenuShowing
```

I litterally copied your question and worked my google-fu on it...

[This was on the first result page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/WebBrowserContextMenu.aspx) :-P