# Disable context menu webbrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the WPF WebBrowser control to display a PDF. I want to disable the context menu.

I have already tried the following -

1. [Disable context menu in Internet Explorer control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656350/disable-context-menu-in-internet-explorer-control) -

   In the constructor, added the following -

   ```
   webBrowser.LoadCompleted +=new LoadCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_LoadCompleted);

   // Event Handler
   public void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e )
   {
       webBrowser.ContextMenu = null;
       var t = webBrowser.Document as System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument;
       // t is always coming as null, even though I can clearly see the pdf in the web browser control.
       if(t != null)
       {
           t.ContextMenuShowing += new System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventHandler(t_ContextMenuShowing);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Also checked http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7c283faf-16c8-4b4e-a362-f292e3032abb/.

   Used the approach to set the registry - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions\NoBrowserContextMenu to DWORD 1.

   When I set the regisrty, the PDF does not get displayed properly.

   Also, since I am using PDF to display, I cannot set - in body -

   ```
   oncontextmenu="return false;"
   ```
3. Cannot set `IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled` as I am using WPF web browser control.

Comment: I cannot ethically help you disable the context menu in a browser. It causes far too much user pain, and can be easily worked around with a little know-how, so relying on it for security is also ethically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the PDF visualizer that wants to show it's own context menu.

Which context menu are you seeing? The one of IE or the one of the PDF visualizer?

I would also try to use the [System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (you can use it in WPF). I used it in a WPF application because it has more functionality than the one of WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the Windows Forms WebBrowser to be bindable and disable the context menu (and access to other properties) in an easy way:

```
public class WindowsFormsWebBrowser : WindowsFormsHost
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Html",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(WindowsFormsWebBrowser),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnHtmlChanged, null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsContentMenuEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsContentMenuEnabled",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(WindowsFormsWebBrowser),
        new PropertyMetadata(true, OnIsContextMenuEnabledChanged));

    private readonly System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

    public WindowsFormsWebBrowser()
    {
        Child = webBrowser;
    }

    public string Html
    {
        get { return GetValue(HtmlProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(HtmlProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool IsContentMenuEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsContentMenuEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsContentMenuEnabledProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnHtmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var browser = d as WindowsFormsWebBrowser;

        if (browser == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        browser.webBrowser.DocumentText = (string)e.NewValue;
    }

    private static void OnIsContextMenuEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var browser = d as WindowsFormsWebBrowser;

        if (browser == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        browser.webBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control) the steps to reference Windows Forms controls in a WPF project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
private void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ((WebBrowser)sender).InvokeScript("eval",
        "$(document).contextmenu(function() { return false; });");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use

```
// Disable the Context menu inside the web browser
webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
```

i tried this in Windows Applications

Comment: He's using WPF, not Windows Forms.